# What are the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora configuration files for in oracle database?

Tags: oracle

I thought that they set network connection so that users can connect to the database. But I just noticed that the last time I transferred the database to another server, I specified "wrong" parameters there, and there were no problems connecting to the database.

In fact, I have now completely cleared the contents of these files, and I do not experience any problems connecting to the database from the application.

Comment: Your application might not be referring to the `tnsnames.ora` - if it connects using a JDBC URL for example. You don't even have to use it with SQL\*Plus, as that allows 'easy connect' syntax which is similar to a JDBC URL. But other things might use it.

Comment: Is there a way to find out if I am setting the parameters in these files correctly?

Comment: You can use the netca tool to update the configuration. (Also note that the `tnsnames.ora` is a *client* file - if you have clients connecting remotely using a TNS alias then they need a correct `tnsnames.ora` on their machine. Anyone connecting locally from the database server but using a TNS alias will need the server version to be correct; or have their own file and their environment set up to find it. The `listener.ora` only needs to exist on the server where the listener is running.)

Comment: But where is listener.ora used? It seems that even when it failed to start everything works just fine.

Comment: The `listener.ora` is used when the listener starts up. If you cleared the file while it was running it wouldn't notice, until you next stop and start it anyway, and you might have broken `lsnrctl`. But it depends what the settings were - they might have been defaults anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `listener.ora` contains the configuration for the database network listener.
- `tnsnames.ora` contains client-side connection descriptions. It is also found on the server, allowing the server to locate some of its own network services, or to locate remote databases for database links.

Together these files generally appear along with `sqlnet.ora` in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory, or in a directory specified in the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable. While deleting the contents of these files may allow Oracle to assume certain defaults and continue working on some level, they often contain security-related parameters that are important for safe operation of the database in a networked environment and should not be left in this state.

Comment: Is there a way to find out if I am setting the parameters in these files correctly?

Comment: @Number02 the documentation for your version of Oracle should always be your first guide. The Network Administrator Guide (or equivalent) has several examples, and definitions for all of the file parameters. As Alex suggested, if you're unfamiliar with the options, use the `netca` utility; it covers all of the basic, and several advanced use cases and will produce all of the files you need.